# Minimum number of groups needed to cover all possible groups of a smaller number

Tags: combinatorics

The specific question is:

In a group of 10 elements, how many groups of 5 elements do we need to pick at minimum so that all possible groups of 3 elements have been chosen?

I know that there are ${10\choose 3}=120$ total groups of 3 elements and each group of 5 contains ${5\choose 3}=10$ groups of 3. But it seems unlikely that we only need 12 groups of 5, because that would imply that we are able to pick them without repeating any groups of 3. I'm a little bit stuck on how to select the groups of 5 in a way that minimizes the amount of overlapping groups of 3 chosen.

Comment: they can't overlap in more that two places to not share groups, 242 groups of 5 to choose from, then 100 to choose one with just 2 overlapping, then ...

Answer (score 1):

Your argument yields a lower bound of $120/10=12$. The [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=10&k=5&t=3) shows that the minimum is 17.

Comment: How does your link get a lower bound of $17$? They only write the word "Schonheim" as justification, but the Schönheim bound (as I understand it from [the second paragraph in this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232224/covering-designs-where-v-is-linear-in-k)) is only $
\left\lceil \frac{10}{5}\left\lceil \frac{9}{4}\left\lceil \frac{8}{3}\right\rceil\right\rceil\right\rceil
=14$.

Comment: More generally, the Schönheim bound refers to the bound $C(v,k,t)\ge \lceil \frac{v}k C(v-1,k-1,t-1)\rceil$, so if you accept that $C(9,4,2)=8$, then you would get $C(10,5,3)\ge \lceil\frac{10}5 C(9,4,2)\rceil=\lceil\frac{10}5 \cdot 8\rceil=16.$ But I still cannot see where $17$ comes from...

Comment: I'm not sure how 17 is obtained as a Schonheim bound, but I did verify optimality of 17 via integer linear programming, with a binary variable for each 5-subset and a constraint for each 3-subset.